# android - specify layout for Galaxy j1 mini

Tags: android, android-layout

They say "density independent" but everything gets broken on Galaxy j1 mini so I need to create layout-xx folder for that. I encountered some troubles with layout-hdpi that caused some problems with another devices (to my surprise, including xhdpi- and xxhdpi-ones) where there should have been the default layout, not the specified.

What specificator do I need to solve the problem with Galaxy j1 mini without harming layouts on other devices where the default layout is sufficient?

Comment: you can make your layout in xml layout-small for small screens

Comment: it won't affect other resolutions, right? and namely "small", not "normal" in my case?

Comment: you will make the both layouts: layout-normal, and layout-small, and in each one you put the resolution of them